# add string time with overflow hour in java

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I want to add string time with format HH:mm:ss and special hour field. Example :
`"20:15:30"` (string) add `"13:50:35"` (string) -> result i want : **"34:06:05"** (string).
I have search similar code :

```
    String time1="20:15:30";
    String time2="13:50:35";

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date1 = timeFormat.parse(time1);
    Date date2 = timeFormat.parse(time2);
    long sum = date1.getTime() + date2.getTime();

    String date3 = timeFormat.format(new Date(sum));
    System.out.println("The sum is "+ date3);
```

And result of above code : `The sum is 10:06:05` not i want. How is easy way to do this ?

Comment: Sounds more like you're talking about a duration or period

Comment: i'm not clear. I just want incremental hour field. Maybe big result similar : "99999:15:05".

Comment: Yeah, so we're talking about a duration of time from 0 to something

Answer (score 2):

You could simply take advantage of either Java 8's or Joda Time's duration capabilities.

For example, this simply creates a duration which is the sum of the number of seconds of the two times

```
LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.parse("20:15:30", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse("13:50:35", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));

//long t = lt1.toSecondOfDay() + lt2.toSecondOfDay();
//Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(t);
Duration duration = Duration.between(lt2, lt1);
System.out.println(formatDuration(duration));
```

Which prints out `34:06:05`

**formatDuration method**

```
public static String formatDuration(Duration duration) {

    long hours = duration.toHours();
    duration = duration.minusHours(hours);
    long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
    duration = duration.minusMinutes(minutes);
    long seconds = duration.getSeconds();

    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` can't do that, but you can do it yourself, by parsing the input with a regular expression, and formatting the output with the `format` method.

```
private static String addTime(String ... times) {
    if (times.length < 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("At least 2 times are required");
    Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])");

    // Parse times and sum hours, minutes, and seconds
    int hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0;
    for (String time : times) {
        Matcher m = timePattern.matcher(time);
        if (! m.matches())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid time: " + time);
        hour   += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        minute += Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        second += Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
    }

    // Handle overflow
    minute += second / 60;   second %= 60;
    hour   += minute / 60;   minute %= 60;

    // Format and return result
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(addTime("20:15:30", "13:50:35"));
System.out.println(addTime("20:15:30", "13:50:35", "20:15:30", "13:50:35"));
System.out.println(addTime("98765:43:21", "12:34:56"));
```

*Output*

```
34:06:05
68:12:10
98778:18:17
```